# define three column primary key in Yii's ORM

Tags: orm, yii

For these three tables, Table XXX has two column composite PK:

```
Table XXX:
 - XXX_id_1
 - XXX_id_2
 - name

Table YYY:
 - YYY_id
 - name

Table XXX_has_YYY:
 - X_id
 - Y_id
 - A_id
```

How can I define this relation in Yii's ORM?

```
public function relations() {
  return array(
      'YYY' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'YYY',
          'XXX_has_YYY(XXX_id_1, XXX_id_2, YYY_id)'),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Please read the documentation.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail)

> Note, for composite foreign keys, they can be either listed together, separated by commas or specified as an array in format of array('key1','key2'). In case you need to specify custom PK->FK association you can define it as array('fk'=>'pk'). For composite keys it will be array('fk_c1'=>'pk_с1','fk_c2'=>'pk_c2').

Also, the second argument refers to the name of the active record class that the related object is of. 
Your relation therefore should look something like this:

```
'XXX_has_YYY_relation_name' => array(self::MANY_MANY, XXX_has_YYY, array(XXX_id_1, XXX_id_2, YYY_id) ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ON` property of [CManyManyRelation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRelation#on-detail)